# Removing navigation buttons from android soft keyboard?

Tags: android

I would like to remove the navigation buttons at the bottom of the soft keyboard ( the buttons with the arrow- they act like a tab key to move between fields). I have had no luck trying to find a way to do this. Does anyone have any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is device-specific, as each device has its own default soft keyboard. Unfortunately, you'll need to make a custom keyboard.

Look at the [Keyboard](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html) class.

Comment: I suppose this is for devices lacking a d-pad or trackball. Do you know if such soft nav keys have to send navigation events when clicked, or is it up to the device manufacturer?

Comment: If you implement your own keyboard, I think you pretty much get free reign on what each key does...but don't quote me on that, I haven't actually ever done that before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to remove the button from the keyboard, but you can at least specify which neighbor the field gives focus to. [See Handling UI Events on the Android Dev Guide.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#HandlingFocus)

Perhaps it's possible to set `nextFocusDown` to nothing, so the keyboard doesn't let the user navigate in that fashion. If that doesn't work, you might consider setting the field that takes focus next to `setFocusable(false)`.